# How do you deploy a release to a sub folder without changing the physical path on IIS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We created a release definition that deploys our build to a onsite IIS server. We need to be able to deploy to a subfolder (e.g. `D:\apps\appname\v1\[deploy here]`. We tried changing the Physical Path setting in the IIS Web App Manage task, but that changes the Physical Path of the entire IIS server.

How can we specify where we want to put our individual application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the IIS Web App Manage task is that it wants to configure and create IIS Web Apps, not just copy files. To just copy files you want to use the Copy Files task. If you're working with a remote machine, make sure you're running the Copy Files task on your deployment group. To do that, in your Release Definition, make sure your task is running under a Deployment group phase that specifies your Deployment Group.

Once you have this set up, your deployment should run, and it will run from whatever machine you configured in the Deployment Group. You can copy files from the build's artifacts to a folder using a path local to that machine. So for example if your IIS Website is located at d:\websites\MySite you would use that as the destination path for the Copy Files task.